# why is this emoji regex also matching numerics

Tags: java, unicode, emoji, java-6

I am writing a program that needs to strip emojis from a string, and found this regex which seems to remove all emojis I have tested it with so far:

```
private static final String EMOJI_REGEX= "[\u200D(?:"
  + "[\uD83C\uDF00-\uD83D\uDDFF]|"
  + "[\uD83E\uDD00-\uD83E\uDDFF]|"
  + "[\uD83D\uDE00-\uD83D\uDE4F]|"
  + "[\uD83D\uDE80-\uD83D\uDEFF]|"
  + "[\u2600-\u26FF]\uFE0F?|"
  + "[\u2700-\u27BF]\uFE0F?|"
  + "\u24C2\uFE0F?|"
  + "[\uD83C\uDDE6-\uD83C\uDDFF]{1,2}|"
  + "[\uD83C\uDD70\uD83C\uDD71\uD83C\uDD7E\uD83C\uDD7F\uD83C\uDD8E\uD83C\uDD91-\uD83C\uDD9A]\uFE0F?|"
  + "[\u0023\u002A\u0030-\u0039]\uFE0F?\u20E3|[\u2194-\u2199\u21A9-\u21AA]\uFE0F?|"
  + "[\u2B05-\u2B07\u2B1B\u2B1C\u2B50\u2B55]\uFE0F?|"
  + "[\u2934\u2935]\uFE0F?|"
  + "[\u3030\u303D]\uFE0F?|"
  + "[\u3297\u3299]\uFE0F?|"
  + "[\uD83C\uDE01\uD83C\uDE02\uD83C\uDE1A\uD83C\uDE2F\uD83C\uDE32-"
  + "\uD83C\uDE3A\uD83C\uDE50\uD83C\uDE51]\uFE0F?|"
  + "[\u203C\u2049]\uFE0F?|[\u25AA\u25AB\u25B6\u25C0\u25FB-\u25FE]\uFE0F?|[\u00A9\u00AE]\uFE0F?|"
  + "[\u2122\u2139]\uFE0F?|\uD83C\uDC04\uFE0F?|\uD83C\uDCCF\uFE0F?|"
  + "[\u231A\u231B\u2328\u23CF\u23E9-\u23F3\u23F8-\u23FA]\uFE0F?)]";
```

When I use this regex like so:

```
strippedString = regexString.replaceAll(EMOJI_REGEX, "");
```

it successfully removes all emojis. However, I tried testing it with data that I wouldn't want stripping, and it seems that this regex also matches numerics. For instance, when I pass the test string `Testing  £1.01☂` the output is `Testing £.`.

I tried removing the `\u0030-\u0039` range from the above regex, but now I am getting `Testing £.0`.

Can anybody advise me as to what is going on here, and how I might resolve the issue?

**Important note** The solution to this problem has to be java 6 compliant, due to ancient architecture.

Comment: My guess is that one of your Emoji Unicode ranges is inadvertantly including numbers.  Pare down your regex until you find the culprit.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen That was my thinking too, but the fact that when I removed \u0030-\u0039 from the regex caused 0 to not be matched, but 1 to be matched makes me question that. Wouldn't that mean that the range would have to include \u0031 and not \u0030, basically meaning it needs to start at \u0031?

Comment: separate ur regex and try each one separately to find the issue, simply put one of the ors is matching something that is not meant to be matched.

Comment: FWIW, if you can use an external library, [I used this](https://github.com/vdurmont/emoji-java) to parse your test string without issue - `EmojiParser.removeAllEmojis("Testing  £1.01☂");` returns `Testing  £1.01`, and is a much nicer solution to maintain than a monster regex.

Comment: @berry120 thanks. i looked into that library, but the impression I get from some of the pull requests is that it's not java 8 compatible. I'll fork it and have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your regular expression is just a bunch of ranges `|`'d together, we can write some test code to see which of the ranges remove the numbers:

```
public class RegexTest
{
    private static final String regexbegin = "[\u200D(?:";
    private static final String regexend = ")]";
    private static final String[] regexparts =
    {
        "[\uD83C\uDF00-\uD83D\uDDFF]",
        "[\uD83E\uDD00-\uD83E\uDDFF]",
        "[\uD83D\uDE00-\uD83D\uDE4F]",
        "[\uD83D\uDE80-\uD83D\uDEFF]",
        "[\u2600-\u26FF]\uFE0F?",
        "[\u2700-\u27BF]\uFE0F?",
        "\u24C2\uFE0F?",
        "[\uD83C\uDDE6-\uD83C\uDDFF]{1,2}",
        "[\uD83C\uDD70\uD83C\uDD71\uD83C\uDD7E\uD83C\uDD7F\uD83C\uDD8E\uD83C\uDD91-\uD83C\uDD9A]\uFE0F?",
        "[\u0023\u002A\u0030-\u0039]\uFE0F?\u20E3",
        "[\u2194-\u2199\u21A9-\u21AA]\uFE0F?",
        "[\u2B05-\u2B07\u2B1B\u2B1C\u2B50\u2B55]\uFE0F?",
        "[\u2934\u2935]\uFE0F?",
        "[\u3030\u303D]\uFE0F?",
        "[\u3297\u3299]\uFE0F?",
        "[\uD83C\uDE01\uD83C\uDE02\uD83C\uDE1A\uD83C\uDE2F\uD83C\uDE32-\uD83C\uDE3A\uD83C\uDE50\uD83C\uDE51]\uFE0F?",
        "[\u203C\u2049]\uFE0F?",
        "[\u25AA\u25AB\u25B6\u25C0\u25FB-\u25FE]\uFE0F?",
        "[\u00A9\u00AE]\uFE0F?",
        "[\u2122\u2139]\uFE0F?",
        "\uD83C\uDC04\uFE0F?",
        "\uD83C\uDCCF\uFE0F?",
        "[\u231A\u231B\u2328\u23CF\u23E9-\u23F3\u23F8-\u23FA]\uFE0F?",
    };

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final String test = "Testing  £1.01☂";
        for (int i = 0; i < regexparts.length; i++) {
            final String regex = regexbegin + regexparts[i] + regexend;
            System.out.println(i + ": " + test.replaceAll(regex, ""));
        }
    }
}
```

Using this code we get:

```
0: Testing  £1.01☂
1: Testing  £1.01☂
2: Testing  £1.01☂
3: Testing  £1.01☂
4: Testing  £1.01
5: Testing  £1.01☂
6: Testing  £1.01☂
7: Testing  £.0☂
8: Testing  £1.01☂
9: Testing  £.☂
10: Testing  £1.01☂
11: Testing  £1.01☂
12: Testing  £1.01☂
13: Testing  £1.01☂
14: Testing  £1.01☂
15: Testing  £1.01☂
16: Testing  £1.01☂
17: Testing  £1.01☂
18: Testing  £1.01☂
19: Testing  £1.01☂
20: Testing  £1.01☂
21: Testing  £1.01☂
22: Testing  £1.01☂
```

So the ranges at index `7` and index `9` are your culprits:

```
"[\uD83C\uDDE6-\uD83C\uDDFF]{1,2}"

"[\u0023\u002A\u0030-\u0039]\uFE0F?\u20E3"
```

Using these directly on a number only test `String`

```
System.out.println("7: " + "0123456789".replaceAll(regexbegin + regexparts[7] + regexend, ""));
System.out.println("9: " + "0123456789".replaceAll(regexbegin + regexparts[9] + regexend, ""));
```

yields this:

```
7: 03456789
9:
```

The former removes 1 and 2, the latter all numbers.

Comment: Thanks Max! Removing the parts at those indexes did solve the issue, so i'm going to mark this as the correct answer. Do you know what it is in those sections that causes the matching of numerics?

Comment: Hard to tell, writing regular expressions is easy, reading them not so much. And all the online parsers I tried can't swallow the ranges with multibyte unicode points.

Answer (score 2):

Max Vollmer already answered but to know why

```
[\u0023\u002A\u0030-\u0039]\uFE0F?\u20E3
```

is matching the numbers, see [Emoji Keyboard/Display Test Data](http://unicode.org/Public/emoji/11.0/emoji-test.txt)

As you can see, `[\u0030-\u0039]\uFE0F?\u20E3` matches to keycap range 0 to 9 (see subgroup: keycap).

As for

```
[\uD83C\uDDE6-\uD83C\uDDFF]{1,2}
```

removing the range `{1,2}` should work.